# Javascript Array not working in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

I've added a sample Javascript array in my web. Funny that it works in jsfiddle but unfortunately not working in Eclipse JSP. Here's the code.

Javascript:

```
var titles  = [];
    var names   = [];
    var tickets = [];

    var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
    var nameInput   = document.getElementById("name");
    var ticketInput = document.getElementById("tickets");

    var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

    function insert() {
     titles.push( titleInput.value );
     names.push( nameInput.value );
     tickets.push( ticketInput.value );

     clearAndShow();
    }

    function clearAndShow () {
      // Clear our fields
      titleInput.value = "";
      nameInput.value = "";
      ticketInput.value = "";

      // Show our output
      messageBox.innerHTML = "";

      messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + titles.join(", ") + "<br/>";
      messageBox.innerHTML += "Names: " + names.join(", ") + "<br/>";
      messageBox.innerHTML += "Tickets: " + tickets.join(", ");
    }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9GAG8/)

Comment: Probably because you are accessing the elements too early. put it inside `window.onload` or have this script after the elements in the html.

Comment: I've added the script onclick in input tag like `onclick="insert()"`

Comment: Nothing happens whenever I clicked the button like what's happening in jsfiddle. I'm very sure I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the page to finish loading all its elements.

You can either do:

```
window.onload=function(){   
                            // Do stuff here       
                        };
```

Or if you are using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
                                   // Do stuff here        
                               });
```